# Setting up DNS on JUJU for local

Tags: networking, juju, dns, bind, dnsmasq

So I have found Juju, which looks amazing! However a huge blocker for me is not knowing how to setup DNS.

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu 14.04LTS with JuJu installed, running local containers. However, I cannot access any of them from the internet. Ideally, I'd like to use existing domains and map them to services running on JuJu such as Worpdress, MediaWiki, etc.

I only have one public IP address (IPv4 but a /64 block of IPv6), I suppose the plan would be to map charms to specific ports then use the nameserver to handle resolution to port.

I'm used to Plesk, cPanel and VestaCP. Do I simply deploy/create a BIND/Webmin Charm for easy DNS mapping or am I totally offbase here?

For clarity, I'd like to setup custom nameservers at my registrar to the server IP (ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com) and have domains, subdomains, etc be routed to specific ports (such as Wordpress running on port 8080 going to name example2.com)

Thanks!

Comment: Here is my JuJu status. As you can see, I set JuJu-GUI to exposed however the "public IP" is not public..   environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.0.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.106
    instance-id: zorrobyte-local-machine-1
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64
services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-24
    exposed: true
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: installing
        agent-version: 1.22.0.1
        machine: "1"
        public-address: 10.0.3.106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the local provider, which is only suitable for development and testing scenarios. For one, as you discovered, the addresses that these containers get are local only.

If you have only one IPv4 address and that's what you want to use, you will have to play with some iptables NAT rules. You could perhaps get away with https://github.com/cmars/juju-nat but I haven't personally used that.

When using juju, you have to pick a provider. The choices are basically cloud and non-cloud. Among the non-cloud ones:

- [manual](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/config-manual): you install the OS, an ssh server, and tell juju to use that machine. It can be a real machine, or a container, KVM instance, etc.
- [MAAS](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/config-maas): more complex but more powerful, with MAAS you can use real machines to deploy juju services and manage DHCP and DNS.

You can probably give the manual provider a try to get your feet wet, but it's quite a bit, er, manual, as the name implies. But could be what you need if you setup the IP and NAT rules appropriately. It loses its appeal once you start handling more dynamic services, because you have to keep provisioning new machines manually for juju to use.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes sense. It's a shame, I'm using http://tutum.co for Docker and it just works and can "bring my own node". I was hoping I could do the same with Juju however it doesn't seem to fit the needs of a SMB/Home Lab as I don't have $$$ for bare metal servers. Juju-Nat looks perfect for my needs, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same juju deployment problem. What I have already done, is to consolidate several http / https services under distinct URLs with Apache2. This is a configuration snipped installed on /etc/apache2/sites-available on my server. It allows public URLs on a single domain name, to be rerouted to any private address.

In my setup, there is a working private DNS, so I can simply route the request to the machine named "jeedom", and I still do not know how to allocate private names to the machines created using Juju. If the IPs of Juju units are stable, specifying an IP is possible. I am convinced that this local DNS question has a simple answer, because on AWS all the VMs get names (even public names).

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin <<email of admin here>>
    ServerName  <<public server DNS>>

    # Does not really matter
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    # SSL specific configuration (there are other ways to configure ssl)
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request.log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    #   See default-ssl site configuration fragment for details.
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/public.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/key.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/1_root_bundle.crt

    # Proxy to jeedom configuration
    # This configuration forwards all https://<<public domain name>>/jeedom urls 
    # to the jeedom embedded web server login screen.
    # Jeedom is a home automation system running on a RaspPi on the LAN

    ProxyRequests off
    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://jeedom/
            ProxyPassReverse http://jeedom/
    </Location>

    # Empty virtual host configuration
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```